# Vim regex to add curly braces every few lines

Tags: json, regex, vim

I am creating a json file and have worked out how to append double quotes and such to appropriate lines, but I need to know how to wrap every 2 lines in curly braces.

Ex:

```
"value": "Bahraini Foreign Ministry"
"tag": "project:bahrain;id:2201",
"value": "Bahraini Foreign Minister"
"tag": "project:bahrain;id:2202",
```

needs to be:

```
{
"value": "Bahraini Foreign Ministry"
"tag": "project:bahrain;id:2201",
},
{
"value": "Bahraini Foreign Minister"
"tag": "project:bahrain;id:2202",
},
```

I have tried with `:%norm` and `:%s` and am going around in circles here. Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: oops, the commas are suppose to be at the end of the value lines

Comment: What is your goal? to use vim regex or to add curly braces where is needed ?

Comment: to add curly braces where is needed in vim. It does not have to be regex

Comment: Run this command: `%s/^"value"/{\r&/g | g/^"tag"/ norm! o},`

Comment: Thanks so much. It worked, but I had to remove the ^

Answer (score 2):

[dNitro's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39044234/vim-regex-to-add-curly-braces-every-few-lines#comment65438478_39044234) is one way to do it. Here is another way:

```
qqqqqqO{<esc>jjo},<esc>j@qq@q
```

This creates a recursive macro, e.g. a macro that calls itself. Since recursive macros run until they hit an error, and calling `j` on the last line throws an error, this will work for any data size. Explanation:

`qqq` clear the register 'q'. `qq` starts recording in register 'q'. `O{<esc>` inserts a bracket on the line above the current line. `jj` moves down (to the line with "tag" on it). `o},<esc>` puts a bracket on the next line after the current one. `j@q` puts on back on a line with "value", and `@q` calls the 'q' macro. Since it's empty while you record, this won't actually do anything. However, once you hit `q@q`, this will stop recording, and then call this recursive macro.

Another alternative is to use the `:global` command, e.g.

```
:g/value/normal O{^[jjo},
```

Note that `^[` is a literal escape character that you must enter by pressing "ctrl-v, ctrl-esc"

This is essentially the same thing, except instead of using a macro, it automatically applies the set of keystrokes after "normal" to every line containing the text "value".

And just for fun, here is one last alternative, a substitute command:

```
:%s/.*"value".*\n.*,/{\r&\r},,
```

This replaces two lines where the first line contains the text `"value"`, with the same text enclosed in brackets.

Comment: simply `:%s/.*\n.*,/{\r&\r},`